# Why is line plot in subplot distorted when using barplot in other subplot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The upper subplot is a perfectly normal ECG signal.
The bottom subplot is a bar plot.

Only on **windows** matlab 2014a, the ECG signal gets screwed up. It seems like it groups data of when zooming in, it seems like the distance between peaks is the same as the width of a bar..

Nothing special happens in the code

why does this happen. both subplots should not even be aware of each other. seems like a bug to me..

```
figure;
subplot(211)
plot(decg.time,decg.values)

subplot(212)

h=bar(d.time,d.values)
```

[image]

Comment: Yup. Seems like a bug. There is no other reasonable explanation. You should report this to MathWorks. I doubt anyone here (other than people who work at MathWorks) can help you. Also, nice job on the MVC.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/accesslogin/login.do?uri=https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/&requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: That's the sloppy version of the bug reporting site.

Comment: @MadPhysicist bummer... What do you mean with MVC ?

Comment: It means I made a typo :-) Meant MCVE. Phone typing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That being said, I did not have a Windows box available to actually verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the issue you are having is the uneven spacing between the bars in your bar plot; to fix this, i would try the following:

- Set the 'barwidth' property to 1: `bar(d.time, d.values, 'barwidth', 1)`
- change the renderer of the figure to painters: `figure('renderer', 'painters');`

In general, both bar and area plots tend to get "screwy" when having a large amount of data points, so resampling the data to a lower resolution might help. Also, the graphics engine has been updated in matlab 2015b, so simply updating might also help, if none of the above suggestions does.